# robot_localization high cpu and no output

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an IMU (orientation only) and rtabmap connected to robot_localization. When I include the pose from the IMU and the odom from rtabmap, robot_localization works fine and uses 1-2% CPU. However, when I add the twist messages from the IMU, robot_localization only produces about 10 messages before ceasing to have any output. When I watch it in htop, it uses 100-105% CPU. I assume that whatever it's doing is blocking indicated by no messages being published and ctrl-c failing to work. I examined the twist data going into robot_localization from the IMU and they look fine. They're coming in at about 375 Hz like the pose messages. rtabmap is coming in at about 10Hz with its odom message. Transforms have been applied, but I'm not sure if they are correct in the way they relate the rtabmap reference frame with the IMU frame. Any idea why this would be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250086/robot_localization-high-cpu-and-no-output/) by [natejgardner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22499/natejgardner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved here: https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/329

---

Originally posted by [natejgardner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22499/natejgardner/) with karma: 36 on 2016-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0